# Steam downloads always stop

Tags: games, steam

Whenever I try to download a game with Steam on Ubuntu 15.04, the download speed will go from 600kb/s-2mb/s to -1kb/s. I've noticed it's usually once the download hits the 30-40mb mark. For example, I was comfortably downloading Toribash with a peak speed of around 900kb/s, and it slowed down to about 600 bytes per second once it hit 35mb. This is incredibly annoying because I've made the change from Windows to Ubuntu on all of my home computers and this is the only program that's giving me grief.
I saw a response on another post that said

> "This happens on Windows too. Its from the steam servers being flooded
>   by downloading the same thing. Its not an Ubuntu bug. Try changing the
>   location settings and check if they are right and just be patient."
>   Now, while this does make sense to most people, it just doesn't seem right in my case. My location settings are exactly the same as they were in Windows, and I've tried downloading multiple games and the same thing happens. If someone could help me solve this, I'd be very grateful. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This does seem to affect Steam on both Windows and Linux, the best way I've found to stop it from happening is to pause the download when the problem starts, then wait 10-15 seconds, then unpause the download and repeat when it happens again.

Comment: 1. That didn't work. 2. Even if it did work, I don't want a lame temporary fix. It'd make big downloads a nightmare.